# Download data from Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am working with RMarkdown file. My file has elements of Shiny but works with flexdashboard. Below you can see the code.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: " "
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---



# Module 1

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(biclust)
data(BicatYeast)
set.seed(1)
res <- biclust(BicatYeast, method=BCPlaid(), verbose=FALSE)

```



## Inputs {.sidebar}

```{r}
 selectInput("clusterNum", label = h3("Cluster number"), 
    choices = list("1" = 1, "2" = 2), 
    selected = 1)
```



## Row {.tabset}


### Parallel Coordinates

```{r}
num <- reactive(as.integer(input$clusterNum))

renderPlot(
  parallelCoordinates(BicatYeast, res, number=num()))

```

### Data for Selected Cluster

```{r}

renderTable(
  BicatYeast[which(res@RowxNumber[, num()]), which(res@NumberxCol[num(), ])]
)

```
````

With the dropdown menu, I can choose a dataset and chooses the data set I can see in the second tab titled as ,Data for Selected Clusteer'.

[image]

Now I want to download the selected table by pressing the download button but I don't know how to do that. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and download data into Excel format (*.xlsx).

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 components:

1. The ability to write a data.frame to an Excel file (or alternativly, just to a CSV file or similar).
2. Make a file downloadable in Shiny.

For the former, take a look at the package `openxlsx`. Avoid the older R package that relies on Java.

For the latter, see this link https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/downloadButton.html (you need to use a downloadLink or downloadButton, and the downloadHandler to generate the output).